# Poco SecureServerSocket without SSLManager

Tags: c++, sockets, ssl, poco

I want to use POCO SecureServerSocket construktor with Context, but I got Exception:
SSL Exception: error:140C5042:SSL routines:SSL_UNDEFINED_FUNCTION:called a function you should not call

I don't want to use SSLManager.
My code:

```
SocketAddress sendSockAdr2("127.0.0.1", 8080);
    Poco::Net::initializeSSL();
    Context::Ptr pContext = new Poco::Net::Context(
                            Poco::Net::Context::CLIENT_USE, "", "", "cacert.pem",
                            Poco::Net::Context::VERIFY_RELAXED, 9, true,
                            "ALL:!ADH:!LOW:!EXP:!MD5:@STRENGTH");
    SecureServerSocket sendSecsrv2(sendSockAdr2,64,pContext);
```

Answer (score 0):

I have bad flag in Context...I had CLIENT_USE instead of SERVER_USE...now it works

```
SocketAddress sendSockAdr2("127.0.0.1", 8080);
Poco::Net::initializeSSL();
Context::Ptr pContext = new Poco::Net::Context(
                        Poco::Net::Context::SERVER_USE, "", "", "cacert.pem",
                        Poco::Net::Context::VERIFY_RELAXED, 9, true,
                        "ALL:!ADH:!LOW:!EXP:!MD5:@STRENGTH");
SecureServerSocket sendSecsrv2(sendSockAdr2,64,pContext);
```